# Не работает PyQt на Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pyqt5, pyqt

Написал IDE на Python и PyQt5. Всю программу писал на Windows, потом вернулся на Ubuntu. На Windows все работало идеально. Запускаю на Ubuntu - вылетает вот эта ошибка:

```
File "/home/alien/PycharmProjects/Test/PyQt_IDE/ide_window.py", line 23, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore' from 'PyQt5' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py)
```

Как это исправить?

upd. Открыл `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/__init__.py`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он оказался пустым, возможно, туда что-то нужно добавить?
В `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/` QtCore присутствует. Значит дело в init файле, скорее всего

Answer (score 0):

Такое впечатление, что что-то не установили.
В windows при активированным виртуальным окружении Python выполните 
*pip freeze > requirements. txt*
.
Этот файл положите в папку проекта на убунте и выполните pip install.

Comment: PyQt пробовал устанавливать в самом PyCharm, устанавливал все зависимости